# Problema de subset no R

Tags: r

Estou com problemas usando `subset` em `R`. Eu acredito que é uma questão fácil, mas eu não estou recebendo direito.

Eu quero fazer um `subset` de dados que posso manter, apenas as observações que não têm o valor da variável `X.trimws.relcoop.SITUAÇÃO ... b ...` não é igual a `Cancelada` e o valor da variável `risco` não igual a `Não classificada`.

Então é isso que eu vim para:

```
dados<-data.frame(subset(dados,(X.trimws.relcoop.SITUAÇÃO...b...!="Cancelada"&risco!="Não classificada")))
```

Também tentei isso:

```
dados<-dados[dados$X.trimws.relcoop.SITUAÇÃO...b... != "Cancelada" & dados$risco!= "Não classificada", ]
```

Mas em ambas o `subset` dos meus dados está se fazendo por `or` em vez de `and`.

Lamento fazer uma pergunta tão fácil, mas acredito que esta resposta vai me ajudar sobre a lógica de `R` e, talvez, pode ajudar os outros.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para retirar apenas as linhas que são "Não Classificadas" e "Canceladas", a forma mais fácil é assim:

Considere este `data.frame`:

```
df <- data.frame(
  x = c("Cancelada", "Outro", "Outro", "Cancelada"),
  y = c("Não classificada", "Não classificada", "Outro", "Outro")
)

subset(df, !(x == "Cancelada" & y == "Não classificada"))
          x                y
2     Outro Não classificada
3     Outro            Outro
4 Cancelada            Outro
```

Você também poderia trocar o `&` (e) por `|` (ou):

```
subset(df, x != "Cancelada" | y != "Não classificada")
```

Comment: Muito bom! Bobeira a minha. Funcionou. Obrigado!

Comment: Legal, se funcionou você pode aceitar a resposta, como mostra o [link](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/a/1079/6036)